# SQL Update or Replace function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which contains multiple columns.

```
Column 1                  Column 2                   Column 3
unique identifier         alphanumerical value       numerical value
```

The unique identifier is currently using the values from Column 2. If I wanted to use the values from Column 3 instead, which would be better suited for my situation? Replace or Update? Or is there another way I should go about doing this.

I'm using TOAD for Oracle for what it is worth.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to change the primary key of your table from "column 2" to "column 3"?

Comment: No. Column 1 was populated with data from Column 2. I need to repopulate it with data from Column 3.

Comment: Is column1 defined as the primary key on the table?

Comment: It is the only column that shows the Null? type as N, so I'm going to assume yes.

Comment: @SD, actually what I want to know is if there is a primary key constraint defined on column1.

Comment: If you can give me a way to check for a primary key constraint I would be happy to look. I am unfamiliar with this database and have nobody to reference for it so I'm coming in blind on this project. I believe the first column was just populated using an exisiting column however.

Comment: SELECT constraint_name FROM all_constraints WHERE constraint_type = 'P' AND table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'; If it returns a name, you have a primary key constraint on the column, which can complicate your efforts if there are foreign keys that depend on it. The table name must be in upper case.

Comment: @SD let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1166/discussion-between-dcookie-and-sd)

Comment: DCookie. I appreciate the helpfulness in the chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF
 you want to make a change in the table THEN
 use UPDATE
ELSE IF
  you want to just view the column1 values mapped with column3 values for particular instance THEN
 use INSERT

The otherway around use UPDATE to change the contents of table, whereas replace is a function which really doesnt makes any changes in the contents of the table but just shows u the changed output.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out what the OP wanted to do was simply set column1 to the value in column3, no replace was necessary. Just a straight update, as in:

```
UPDATE TheTable SET column1 = column3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use both.

```
update sometable set column1 = replace(column1,column2,column3)
```

You might want to do the following first to make sure you're replacing what you want to replace:

```
select replace(column1,column2,column3) from sometable
```

Comment: I will try this implementation as soon as I am able to. Looks like I can just use a straight assignment rather than using a replace.

Comment: Yes, the only thing you need to be careful of is what DCookie is trying to get at. If the column1 field is a primary key, there are probably a couple of constraints on the field.  Look at the all_constraints or dba_constraints tables to check.